# C++ will ifdef block cause ABI compatibility issues?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, abi

Let's say we're building a library `mylib` and below is the header file

```
# mylib.h

// some include 

#ifdef ENABLE_XXX_FEATURE
#include <dependent_library_a>
#include <dependent_library_b>
#endif


class MyLib {
...

#ifdef ENABLE_XXX_FEATURE
void feature_xxx_related_function(type_in_dependent_library_a param1, type_in_dependent_library_b param2);
#endif

};
```

I want to use the `ENABLE_XXX_FEATURE` definition to control the visibility of some code blocks.   If user doesn't need feature xxx, then he won't define `ENABLE_XXX_FEATURE` and thus he won't see `#include <dependent_library_a>`and `#include <dependent_library_b>`, and he doesn't have to install those libraries.

The code block inside `ifdef` involves some very heavy dependencies and most user doesn't need them at all and obviously, I don't want them to install those dependencies.

My only concern is the ABI compatibility:

- when I compile `mylib` I will enable the `ENABLE_XXX_FEATURE` and the output `.so` file will contain all the things inside `ifdef` block.
- when user include my header without defining `ENABLE_XXX_FEATURE`, he will see a different definition of `class MyLib`, and when he try to link my `mylib.so` will this cause any ABI compatibility issues?

Comment: Yes, if feature_xxx_related_function is a virtual function.

Comment: @S.M. I suppose this just applies to normal ABI rules, for example adding a new field in the `ifdef` block also breaks the ABI, right?

Comment: Right..........

Comment: And pedantically, there is ODR violation anyway as `class MyLib` has different definition in your lib and for user.